# Trying to connect to SQLalchemy engine

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

So i have a YAML file with the following parameters which I read into a dictionary
The part i don't get is how to connect it to the SQL engine, I have looked at the documentation and what i need is to break the creds as

```
dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database
```

but i'm not sure what the dialect and drive is in this case

```
RDS_HOST: XXXX.YYYYY.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
RDS_PASSWORD: XXXXXX
RDS_USER: XXXXXX
RDS_DATABASE: postgres
RDS_PORT: XXXX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialect can either be `mysql` or any relational database management system it supports.

For `mysql` the driver is `mysqldb`.

For `postgresql` the driver is `psycopg2`.

**Note:** You may need to install the driver too

Comment: Thank you, Yeah i figured it out yesterday but took me so long, It was quite simple when  I saw the previous answer and your answer too

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
connection_string = f"postgresql://{RDS_USER}:{RDS_PASSWORD}@{RDS_HOST}:{RDS_PORT}/{RDS_DATABASE}"
```

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi! When answering a question, it's best to explain why your solution works. That way, it's easier to implement in an existing codebase, and it's also easier to tell why it works.

Comment: Thank you for you reply, It worked after figuring out what dialect and driver meant everything else you wrote was spot on